# Unable to install proxy pac file on browser

Tags: proxy, pac

I wrote a proxy pac file and hosted it on my apache tomcat server.
Upon much research, i came up with this code to direct a proxy to the following ip address.
However , it does not redirect to my proxy at all

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
 { if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.112.0", "255.255.255.0"))
      return "PROXY 192.168.112.167:8080; DIRECT";
   else return "DIRECT"; }
```

I checked it time and time again and i see nothing wrong with it.
Since there are not much debugging tools in pac files.
I tried using alert in IE however nothing appears.
Then i tried using firefox`s web developer mode to see what`s wrong with it
Apparently it has a syntax error, may i know what is wrong with it?
All the sites i referenced are showing the same syntax and all